# Remove labels created from same variable

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I want to remove certain labels from my screen. The problem is that I do not know how to access each label individually. I created each label using the same variable, `tile_frame_column`, 
Let's say the following letters are on my screen: 'a' 'r' 'p' 'd' 'e' 'j': I would like to remove 'r' 'e' 'd' but each of those letters was created by `tile_frame_column`

I tried using `tile_frame_column.place_forget()` but it only removes the last letter which was created - 'j'. How can I access those relevant labels?

Code Below:

```
def add_letter():
   global tile_frame_column
   global list_to_string
   global i
   global j
   if not tiles_letter:
       return
   rand = random.choice(tiles_letter)
   tile_frame_column = Label(root, text=rand)  # each letter is created from tile_frame_column
   tile_frame_column.place(x=i, y=j)  # I place random letters on the screen
   tiles_letter.remove(rand)  # remove that tile from list of tiles
   i+=20
   if (len(tiles_make_word) % 12 == 0) & (len(tiles_make_word) > 0):
       i=35
       j+=20
       tile_frame_column.place(x=i, y=j)
       i+=20
   tiles_make_word.append(rand)
   list_to_string = ''.join(tiles_make_word)  # converts each letter in list to a string
   root.after(1000, add_letter)

root.after(1000, add_letter)
```

Comment: You need to keep a reference to them, e.g. in a list.

Comment: but how do I access the labels from the new list? Can i make a list of labels? (sorry I'm a noob at programming)

Comment: The same way you *"make a connection"* with anything else; yes, you can put a `tk.Label` in a list. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the proposed answers, i'd recommend to use a dictionary instead of a list. This gives you the option to give the labels a key, which could make finding the label you want to remove a lot easier. This is an example:

This generates labels with a random character and puts the labels in `self.dict` under the key which is the character. This way you can delete the label easily when you know the character it contains. In this example you can enter the character of the label you want to remove in the entry and it removes that label.

Note that you would have to think about how to use this when you have two of the same letters, because the second label will replace the first in the dictionary when you try to put in under the same key. You an check if it already exists using `if letter in self.dict.keys():`

```
import Tkinter as tk
import random
import string

class App():

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.dict={}
        button1 = tk.Button(self.root, text='print dict', command=self.print_dict)
        button1.pack()
        button2 = tk.Button(self.root, text='insert label', command=self.insert_label)
        button2.pack()
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        entry = tk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.var)
        entry.pack()
        button3 = tk.Button(self.root, text='delete label', command=self.delete_label)
        button3.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def insert_label(self):
        letter = random.choice(string.letters)
        # you could put something like
        # if not letter in self.dict.keys():
        # here to prevent making two of the same labels
        self.dict[letter] = tk.Label(self.root, text=letter)
        self.dict[letter].pack()

    def print_dict(self):
        print self.dict

    def delete_label(self):
        letter = self.var.get()
        try:
            self.dict[letter].pack_forget()
            del self.dict[letter]
            self.var.set('')
        except:
            self.var.set('Label unknown')

App()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create another variable, `num_labels` which counts the number of labels made, then use that variable in the label variables name e.g.

```
global num_labels
num_labels = 0
def add_letter():
    global num_labels
    num_labels += 1
    tiles_frame_column = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] # etc. however many numbers you have.
    tiles_frame_column[num_labels] = Label(root, text=rand)
    # and carry on with rest of code
```

Then you would have to test each label number to see what letter it is when you want to delete some letters.

Comment: let's say I have 200 letters. Is there a quick way to do 1-200 instead of writing each number out. [1,2,3,4,5,6,.......]

Comment: there are only 26 letters in the english language?

Comment: I have never used a dictionary, but it probably works fine, try that.